# IOS Swift Protocol is not working or hitting breakpoint

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-protocols, avplayerviewcontroller

I created a question a few days ago and was provided with protocol on how to solve an issue of passing data back and forth . I have also looked at some tutorials and have created a protocol but it is not working or even hitting the breakpoint from what I can see it should be working. I have created a protocol for my AVPlayer so that on tap it could get a new video but like i said it's not even hitting the breakpoint this is my code...

```
protocol CustomAVPLayerProtocol: class {
   func reloadTabled(at index: Int)
}
class CustomAVPLayerC: AVPlayerViewController {

  var delagate: CustomAVPLayerProtocol?

   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {



    self.delagate?.reloadTabled(at: 1)
            for touch in touches {

                   self.delagate?.reloadTabled(at: 1)
                    print("Tapped")
                // When I tap the AVPlayer this print statement shows
               // So I know it is coming here
            }

    }
  }
```

Now This is my second class/controller

```
class BookViewC: UIViewController, CustomAVPLayerProtocol {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       PlayVideo(250, "url")

    }

func reloadTabled(at index: Int) {
        print("This protocol method does not execute or hit breakpoint")
        self.PlayVideo(250, "url")
    }


    func PlayVideo(MediaHeight: Float, MediaURL: String) {

        let movieURL = URL(string: MediaURL)

        videoCapHeight.constant = CGFloat(MediaHeight)
        streamsModel.playerView = AVPlayer(url: movieURL!)
        streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.player = streamsModel.playerView
        streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue
        streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = false
        streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.view.frame = VideoView.bounds
        VideoView.addSubview(streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.view)
        self.addChildViewController(streamsModel.MyAVPlayer)
        streamsModel.playerView?.isMuted = false
        streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.player?.play()
    }



}
```

**As I stated before it is not even hitting the breakpoint on** BookViewC.reloadTabled as suggestions would be great

Comment: In this isolated example, the protocol has nothing to do with your question. Protocols are often paired with delegates and so many people think that to use a delegate there must be a protocol lurking, which is not the case. You want two view controllers to communicate with each other, which can be done in a number of ways, with or without a protocol. They can communicate forward without using anything fancy, backward using a delegate, through a shared object (which can be static or not), through observers, etc. Does one view controller instantiate the other?

Comment: you are not setting protocol delegate in BookViewVC

Comment: Yes the BookView controller has a UIview called VideoView which you can see inside the method PlayVideo, that UIView I changed it to play a video so it becomes a AVPlayer . The class CustomAVPLayer controls the functionality of the AVPlayer in BookView . Interestingly enough I created an Observer and have it working .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the foundation set up correctly but remember that classes are (mostly) just blueprints for instances. These classes are useless until you create instances of them because it’s the instances that will do the work.

Therefore, simply pass one instance as the delegate of the other, which you can do here because you've correctly set up the protocol.

```
protocol CustomAVPLayerProtocol: AnyObject {
    func reloadTabled(at index: Int)
}

class CustomAVPLayerC: AVPlayerViewController {
    weak var delagate: CustomAVPLayerProtocol?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.delagate?.reloadTabled(at: 1)

        for touch in touches {
            self.delagate?.reloadTabled(at: 1)
            print("Tapped")
        }
    }
}

class BookViewC: UIViewController, CustomAVPLayerProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        PlayVideo(250, "url")
    }

    func reloadTabled(at index: Int) {
        PlayVideo(250, "url")
    }

    func PlayVideo(_ MediaHeight: Float, _ MediaURL: String) {
        //
    }
}

let book = BookViewC()
let layer = CustomAVPLayerC()
layer.delagate = book
```

Where you do this instantiation/delegation is up to you. Also, I know that a lot of people here use `class` to define protocols that only conform to classes, but Swift's documentation instructs us to use `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 3):

As per your code these are some minor mistakes which you can correct to make it work.

```
1. `weak var delagate: CustomAVPLayerProtocol?`
      *Make a weak delegate to save it from retaining a strong reference cycle and memory leaks.*

2. Code Snippet:

    func PlayVideo {
    let customPlayer = CustomAVPLayerC()
    customPlayer.delegate = self 
}
```

*in Your Second ViewController, You need to assign your delegate to an object / view controller to make ie respond to*

> NOTE: In case you require, you can make a super class that conforms the your protocol class, so that your every view controller conforms it automatically, you just need to assign an delegate to class on which you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Protocols are the most common means used by unrelated objects to communicate with each other. As per the above code, the communication did not seem to happen.

Your protocol declaration part seems alright. The problem exists in the secondViewController. I can see that you have not set the delegate to the object that's been created. Ideally, it has to be something like this:

```
Class BookViewC: UIViewController, CustomAVPLayerProtocol {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       PlayVideo(250, "url")

}
```

You need to the set the delegate here:

```
func PlayVideo {

let customPlayer = CustomAVPLayerC()
customPlayer.delegate = self //This makes the selector to respond

}
```

Comment: This is a common misconception about protocols in Swift. Protocols are just a promise to implement specific properties and methods, they don't themselves do any of the communication.